# Building Poco with Custom OpenSSL

Tags: linux, openssl, poco-libraries

I need to build Poco using the OpenSSL that I built from source, rather than the one installed by Ubuntu's `apt`.  Let's say my OpenSSL root is in `/opt/openssl/1.0.2`.  Do I need to set environment variables, or pass parameters to the `configure` or `make` steps?  I'm not finding any info in the docs, or anywhere else, on how to do this.

Due to other constraints, I am also limited to Poco 1.7.7, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--include-path` and `--library-path` with `configure` to set the search paths so that your custom OpenSSL library will be found, e.g.:

```
./configure --include-path=/opt/openssl/1.0.2/include --library-path=/opt/openssl/1.0.2/lib
```

You can also create a custom build configuration file (see `build/config` directory for existing configurations) or change an existing one and modify the compiler and linker flags to add the search paths.

Comment: You have a '=' where there should be a '-' in the include path.  SO won't let me edit it, because "edits must be 6 characters or more."  Maybe it'll let you fix it.  I'll mark it as the accepted answer if you can do this.